# how to apply not equal to filter in jquery dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Hi guys I'm creating an asp.net mvc 5 application using database first approach. I wrote this code of jquery in my master layout ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("select").prepend("<option value=''>Select one</option>");
 $("select option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");
})
```

Now all of the select tags are having a 'select one' option. Now I'm  facing a scenario in which I'm passing a value to a create function where I have to select a dropdown option who match with that value like if i pass the value item then the dropdown option having value item will be selected. I'm doing this with jquery.

Jquery code of selection is working fine but because I'm prepending 'Select one' its appearing on select list by default and in html I can see two options with selected property but browser is showing me select one because its on top in options.

One approach to fix this is to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("select .dropdown").prepend("<option value=''>Select one</option>");
 $("select .dropdown option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");
})
```

that all the select lists with a specific class name should have 'Select one' option but there are about more that one hundred select tags and I don't want to visit every page and add class to select tags.

Is there any way to apply such filter in jquery that don't apply this prepend to all of the select lists who have a specific class name. or any other related solution.

Comment: You're probably after either jQuery's [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function, or the CSS [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#select option[value='']").remove()

I removed the select one option and its started to work.